# Aggregate Jest Tests / Coverage from two (or many) directories

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

### Goal

I need to generate a solid coverage report from jest that summarizes over a couple directories.

- `frontend/components/FOO/our_feature`
- `frontend/components/BAR/our_feature`

I can get the coverage report from one folder via

`yarn test frontend/components/FOO/our_feature --coverage --collectCoverageFrom='frontend/components/FOO/our_feature/**/*'`

Which is great and tells me quite a lot, however only within the `FOO/our_feature` directory. What would be even better is if I can get a coverage report to also include everything within `BAR/our_feature`.

Having two separate coverage reports isn't the best in this case since one coverage report mentions that `FOO` has 50% coverage, and `BAR` 15% coverage. Coverage on `FOO + BAR` captures exactly what we want.

**Bottom Line** - How do I get jest coverage over two (or more) directories?

## SOLVED

Just throw wildcards at the paths.

```
yarn test frontend/components/**/our_project--coverage --collectCoverageFrom='frontend/components/**/our_project/**/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just have to throw wildcards at the paths...

```
yarn test frontend/components/**/our_project--coverage --collectCoverageFrom='frontend/components/**/our_project/**/*'
```